IP address being constrained outside Netplan
I have just done a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04 to run one application, iRedMail.
I have set a fixed IP:
sudo nano  /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.x.xx/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 208.67.222.222]

but, after a restart, I get:
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:db:88:fe:a8:2b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s0
    inet xx.xx.xx.xx/22 metric 100 brd 192.168.3.255 scope global dynamic eno1
       valid_lft 6253sec preferred_lft 6253sec
    inet6 ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I have changed the IP in the yaml file, but it doesn't have any effect on the value from ip a
I can force a change with
sudo ip addr add inet xx.xx.xx.xx/24 dev eth0

but on restart we go back to the original value.  Can anyone explain this behaviour?  Most puzzling to me is the change of the sub-net mask from 24 to 22.

The interface in output of ip a is eno1, but you have it as enp2s0 in your Netplan config. Change to the following:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.xx/24]
      routes:
         - to: default
           via: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 208.67.222.222]

Then run sudo netplan apply.

Note:
gateway4 has been deprecated, so I swapped it out with routes.
See gateway4 definition here.
Documentation to define default routes can be read here.

You didn't state in your question whether you had more than one YAML configuration file. Your comment indicates that you did. Therefore, files named in a higher lexicographical order will override earlier configuration settings. Per the netplan-generate(8) manpage:

If there are files with different names, then they are considered in
lexicographical order
- regardless of the directory they are in.  Later files add to or override earlier  files.
For example, /run/netplan/10-foo.yaml would be updated by /lib/netplan/20-abc.yaml.
   If you have two files with the same key/setting, the following rules apply:

   • If  the  values are YAML boolean or scalar values (numbers and strings) the old value is
     overwritten by the new value.

   • If the values are sequences, the  sequences  are  concatenated  -  the  new  values  are
     appended to the old list.

   • If  the  values  are mappings, netplan will examine the elements of the mappings in turn
     using these rules.



Thanks mpboden, but it didn't change the behaviour. I did adopt the changes you suggested (I forgot that gateways4 had been deprecated and was cut-and-pasting from an earlier template). What did work was to move the default 50-cloud-init.yaml file out of the /netplan directory. I remember reading that all the yaml files are executed, so I think that the earlier settings were being saved in the cloud and re-installed. It looks right now.

Glad it worked out. You didn't mention in your question that you had more than one YAML file. So yes, all YAML files are rendered as you figured out.
